# implode() [function.implode]

Tags: php

I'm getting an error **Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/social/public_html/form_test.php on line 13** I'm not sure why i'm getting this error.

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet']))
    foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value) 
    $_POST['wmeet'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
    $wmeet = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet']);

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($wmeet); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Maybe the missing braces is a result of copy and paste from the actual file to SO.  I overlooked the braces in my answer, given below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using braces. When you check `is_array`, the `if` statement only applies to the following line (the `for each`). The `for each` is only being applied to the following line as well, then the `if` block ends.

This means that when you use `implode()`, it is outside of the `if` block, and therefore not ensuring that your argument is an array. You should look at Alex's answer and adjust your code accordingly, so that the `implode()` line is within the `if` block.

Your code right now is functioning like this:

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value) {
        $_POST['wmeet'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
    }
}

$wmeet = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet']);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($wmeet); echo '</pre>';
```

When it should be like this:

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value) {
        $_POST['wmeet'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
    }

    $wmeet = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet']);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($wmeet); echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from your indenting, but your problem may be missing braces. You need them to run more than one line of code in a conditional or loop:

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value) {
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm guessing what's happening is that the implode() is running when wmeet is not an array because of the missing braces.

Answer (score 2):

Your implode function is getting called even when the `is_array($_POST['wmeet']` condition is false. Use braces you have that inside your if condition

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value) 
    $_POST['wmeet'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
    $wmeet = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet']);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($wmeet); echo '</pre>';
}
```

Also you might want to add the foreach statement in braces as follows:

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $_POST['wmeet'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
    }
    $wmeet = implode(" ",$_POST['wmeet']);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($wmeet); echo '</pre>';
}
```

**Edit**: I just noticed that you are trying to implode an associative array. I don't think implode works on associative arrays.

I found this code on php.net (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#103861 by tl at magus dot dk) for associative arrays which might be useful for you.

$assoc_array = array("Key1" => "Value1", "Key2" => "Value2");

$new_array = array_map(create_function('$key, $value', 'return $key.":".$value." # ";'), array_keys($assoc_array), array_values($assoc_array));

print implode($new_array);

Which will output:

Key1:Value1 # Key2:Value2 #

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `$_POST['wmeet']` is an associative array.

Maybe something like:

```
$new_array = array_map(create_function('$key, $value', 'return $key."=".$value;'), array_keys($_POST['wmeet']), array_values($_POST['wmeet']));
print implode(" ", $new_array);
```

That will make $_POST['wmeet'] associative array into a normal array that you can later implode.

It will print something like

```
key1=value1 key2=value2 ... keyN=valueN
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember being possible to do implode to a $_POST value. And check those brackets to

Try

```
if (is_array($_POST['wmeet']))
{
    $postWmeet = $_POST['wmeet'];
    foreach ($_POST['wmeet'] as $key => $value)
    {
       $postWmeet[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($value));
       $wmeet = implode(" ",$postWmeet);

       echo '<pre>'; print_r($wmeet); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```